# Limit query by sum of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table, transactions, with fields id, transactionType, quantity, price etc. I want to limit records by the cumulative sum of one column. So I want to pull out all the transactions until the cumulative quantity reaches my variable (here <=50).

What am I doing wrong?

```
SET @qsum := 0; 
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, (@qsum := @qsum + quantity) AS cumulative_quantity 
  FROM transactions ORDER BY id DESC
) transactions 
WHERE 
transactionType = 'buy'
AND typeID = 10
AND cumulative_quantity <= 50
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept any answers with the Green checkmark whose ever it is if appropriate. That is our feedback for our efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SET @qsum := 0; 
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, (@qsum := @qsum + quantity) AS cumulative_quantity 
  FROM transactions
  WHERE transactionType = 'buy'
   AND typeID = 10
   AND cumulative_quantity <= 50
  ORDER BY id DESC
) transaction
```